# Optimal Receiver Using Complex Baseband

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications

Given the below signals and a square pulse shape, I want to design the optimal receiver using complex baseband:

$s_0 = p(t)sin(300\pi t)$

$s_1 = p(t)sin(301\pi t)$

I know that I will be using a matched filter and try to find the filter with the max correlation with any particular signal. The part I am confused by is the difference in the frequency between $s_1$ and the demodulator signals at the receiver. How should this be incorporated into the receiver?

[image: Pulse shape and transmitter signals]

[image: Receiver design]

Comment: Are you positive that the duration of $p(t)$ is $1 \mu s$?

Comment: It isn't a physical implementation, just a theoretical question. You can make it 1 ms or 1 s if that helps.

Comment: When using FSK as you are, it is generally advisable to have the two frequencies be separated by at least $T^{-1}$ Hz, where $T$ is the symbol duration ($1 \mu$s in your example). It might be worth considering whether your example satisfies this requirement. Alternatively, _sketch_ the two signals for one data bit and think about how similar the two signals are in the time interval $[0,10^{-6}]$.

Comment: $\uparrow$ What Dilip said.